# Makefile compare strings resulting in shell command

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following (part of a larger multiline bash script) in my makefile. The variables `A`, `B` come from shell command execution via `$$(...)`, but the code below is enough to reproduce the problem:

```
test:
    A=1; \
    B=2; \
    diff < ( echo $$A ) < ( echo $$B ) || exit 1
```

> syntax error near unexpected token `('.

How can this be done in make? I know there is `ifeq` and similar in Makefile, but I guess its not suitable for multiline bash scripts in Makefiles.

Comment: Dont leave a space between `<(`. Also $$ is the PID of the current process so you are comparing PIDA and PIDB, you never use the variables you set.

Comment: @User112638726 In his Makefile context, `$$` will result in the shell seing `$`.

Comment: @PSkocik ahh right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax of Process substitution is

```
<( echo $$A )
```

i.e. no space between `<` and `(`.

Be sure to specify

```
SHELL ::= /bin/bash
```

or some other shell that supports it.

Comment: thanks, I ended up pulling all the bash related things to a separate `.sh` file with bash shebang

Answer (score 2):

The default shell is `/bin/sh` which doesn't have Process Substitution.
You need to change the shell:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
test:
    A=1; \
    B=2; \
    diff <( echo $$A ) <( echo $$B ) || exit 1
```